# Why doesn't 404 kick in when a bad URL is entered?

Tags: redirects, 404

Most people don't want to get a 404 page, however, I am having issues with a site where 404 pages don't show when you enter an erroneous URL.

Example: http://livefreehomehealthcare.com/products/asdasdasdasd/ does not exist, but instead of a 404 page, which has been created and works (see example), I get the products page or segment_1 of the URL.

It appears that if segment_1 is a valid part of the URL then the strict URL rule that should redirect to the 404 page doesn't fire properly.

I am running EE 2.5.2

Update: MediaGirl suggested below that I use the require_entry="yes" parameter in the channel tags. I did this and it works *too well*.

Here's what I mean. I am using the index template of the template group for the "home" page for the section so that "our products" shows up as /products/ instead of /products/our-products. Here is the code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" entry_id="12"}
<h2>{title}</h2>
{body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This displays the content fine, but is also open to 404 failure. So I tried this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" entry_id="12" require_entry="yes"}
{if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}    
<h2>{title}</h2>
{body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

When I do it this way 404 works too well and I can't see the contents of the /product/ page.

Is there a happy medium here?

Any ideas for getting this to work correctly would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll likely get a better answer if you post some simplified template code so we know how you are using your 'products/index' template. Also, for starters, check that you have [strict urls](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html#strict-urls) enabled. This is a helpful article on ensuring 404s in a variety of situations: [Guide to 404 Pages with ExpressionEngine](http://joviawebstudio.com/index_ee.php/blog/guide_to_404_pages_with_expressionengine/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are hard-coding an `entry_id` in your `channel:entries` tag in your `products/index` template, and *as long you don't need any additional url segments to trigger other behavior*  (such as pagination or for dynamically loading another entry), you could just do this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" entry_id="12"}
    {if segment_2 != ""}
        {redirect="404"}
    {/if}
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, this is a good idea but what happens of someone thumbs it and types: /products/abd ?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, that's exactly the scenario in which you _wanted_ to trigger a 404. Since /products/abd wouldn't be a valid URL. Correct? Or did I misinterpret your question?

Comment: Hi Alex, gotcha. I see what you are saying here. I misread the != as ==. Thanks.

Comment: A great link to bookmark regarding the entire 404 topic in EE is: http://joviawebstudio.com/index_ee.php/blog/guide_to_404_pages_with_expressionengine/ . I refer to it regularly.

Answer (score 12):

There are 3 things that should fix this.

1. Assign your 404 error template in your "[**Global Template Preferences**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html)" which can be found at Design > Templates > Template Preferences
2. In your **products** template, add the `require_entry="yes"` parameter to your channel:entries tag
3. Inside that channel:entries tag add the following to redirect incorrect requests to the 404:

   ```
   {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
   ```

Comment: Also relevant to this question is [Erik's copious answer here](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1227/55).

Comment: Thanks for the response. In theory this sounds good, however, I am still getting an error on the main products page. Please see my modified question above.

Comment: Please post the complete template code to pastie.org and paste the link back here as a comment. I'm not able to help further without seeing all you code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using dynamic:

```
{
    exp:channel:entries
    channel="product"
    dynamic="yes"
}
```

Make sure you add

```
    require_entry="yes"
```

Otherwise EE will load ALL entries... in other words:

```
if(entry found) {
    show entry;
}
else if (dynamic && !require_entry) {
    denial_of_service_attack(self);
}
```